# Common header and footer in two separate angular 6 projects?

Tags: angular

I want to create a new angular 6 project and for which I want to reuse the header, footer and few other components from another existing angular project.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular 6 library feature that is implemented to create reusable components across projects.

Angular library can be generated with the help of **@angular/cli** or **ng** command.

```
ng generate library name --prefix=lib
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, You can reuse them.

for example:

`<app-header></app-header>`

`<app-footer></app-footer>`
...